# How to Create Validation in Spinner in android?

Tags: android

How to use Set Error in Spinner? I tried by typecast textview but it do not generate error message.

```
submitBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String patt = "";
        boolean b1 = check(name, patt);
        if (!b1) {
            allergy_nameEt.setError("Enter Disease Name");
            return;
        }
        boolean patt1 = doctor_name.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select Doctor");
        boolean b2 = check(spin, String.valueOf(patt1));
        if (!b2) {
            ((TextView) doctor_name.getSelectedView()).setError("Please Select Doctor");
            return;
        } else {
            new allergy_category().execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Implementing in the following manner:

```
static public void setSpinnerError(Spinner spinner, String errormsg){
    View selectedView = spinner.getSelectedView();
    if (selectedView != null && selectedView instanceof TextView) {
        TextView selectedTextView = (TextView) selectedView;
        selectedTextView.setError(errormsg);
    }
}
```

set `error` to null if you want to dismiss it.